# Error de Validación de DNI C++

Tags: c++, funciones, booleano, dni

Hola tengo un PROBLEMA con este código para validar un DNI. Me pidieron escribir una función que dado un número de DNI, retorne True si el número es válido y False si no lo es. Para que un número de DNI sea válido debe tener 10 dígitos pero al momento de escribir más de 10 dígitos el programa me retorna un true, cuando debería ser false.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int DNI(int n){
    int x=0;
    bool DNI;
    while (n>0){
        n=n/10;
        x++;
    }
    DNI=x==10;
    cout<< std::boolalpha;
    cout<<"El numero de DNI es: "<<DNI;

    return DNI;
}
int main(){
    int n,fun;
    cout<<"Ingrese su numero de DNI: ";cin>>n;
    fun=DNI(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Intenté con varias versiones del código sin usar funciones para ver si funcionaba y nada.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n,x=0;
    cout<<"Ingrese su numero de DNI: ";cin>>n;
    while (n>0){
        n=n/10;
        x++;
    }
    if (x!=10){
        cout<< std::boolalpha;
        cout<<false;
    }
    else{
        cout<< std::boolalpha;
        cout<<true;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Otra versión pero con while (tampoco funcionó)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n,x=0;
    cout<<"Ingrese su numero de DNI: ";cin>>n;
    while (n>0){
        n=n/10;
        x++;
    }
    while (x!=10)
    {
        cout<< std::boolalpha;
        cout<<false;
        cout<<"Ingrese de nuevo: ";cin>>n;
    }
    cout<< std::boolalpha;
    cout<<true;

    return 0;
}
```

Cuando el DNI tiene menos de 10 dígitos funciona correctamente mostrando un false de que el DNI es incorrecto, pero cuando es mayor a 10 en vez de mostrar el false diciendo que el DNI está incorrecto, el programa entrega un true haciendo pasar al DNI incorrecto como si estuviera bien.

Comment: ¿Por qu´q almacenas el DNI como un entero? Si no vas a hacer operaciones matemáticas con esa variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int` suele ser un entero de 32 bits, y el número más grande que puede representar es **2147483647**, que casualmente tiene 10 dígitos. Como dice [la documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt), al ingresar un número mayor al máximo posible, guarda el máximo valor posible en la variable.

> - If `lval < std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`, sets failbit and stores `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` to `val`.
> - Otherwise, if `std::numeric_limits<int>::max() < lval`, sets failbit and stores `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` to `val`.
> - Otherwise, stores `static_cast<int>(lval)` to `val`.

¿Qué opciones tienes?

- Usar un tipo más grande. Por ejemplo [`long long int`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Integer_types).
- La documentación dice que cuando el valor está fuera del rango representable también establece el bit de fallo. Así que puedes verificar que el bit no esté activado con [`fail()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail):

  ```
  cout << "Ingrese su numero de DNI: "; cin >> n;

  if (cin.fail()) {
      cout << "El numero ingresado es demasiado grande\n";
  }
  else {
      fun = DNI(n);
  }
  ```
- Guardar el número como un [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), verificar si es un número y los dígitos que tiene.

  ```
  string n;
  cout << "Ingrese su numero de DNI: "; cin >> n;

  if (n.length() != 10 || !es_numero(n)) {
      cout << "No es válido\n";
  }
  ```

  Recuerda agregar `#include <string>` si quieres usar strings. En [esta página](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4654636) puedes encontrar diferentes formas de verificar si un string es número.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque los DNI son valores numéricos no deben guardarse como int sino como cadena de caracteres, lo mismo ocurre por ejemplo con los números de teléfono, ISBN, cuentas bancarias, etcétera.

Tú código quedaría así:

```
int main()
{
    char DNI[100];

    cout<<"Ingrese su número de DNI: ";
    cin>>DNI;

    int length = strlen(DNI);
    
    if(length == 10)
    {
        //DNI válido
    }
    else
    {
        //DNI inválido 
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Se declara la **variable DNI** que es un arreglo de caracteres, la variable length calcula la longitud del arreglo de caracteres, de ser 10 la longitud el DNI es válido, caso contrario es invalido.

Revisa bien mi propuesta y adáptala a tus necesidades.